# Rails 4: custom action to update only one param with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `Calendar` and a `Post` models, using `shallow` routes:

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :posts, shallow: true
end
```

A calendar `has_many` post and a post `belong_to` a calendar.

I am already using an AJAX call on the `Posts#Update` action in the **post** `show.html.erb` view to update the custom `:approval` param of a post:

- I have `respond_to do |format| format.js end` in my `Posts#Update` controller
- I have an `update.js.erb` view in `app/views/posts/` to reload the corresponding section of the post `show.html.erb` view
- And of course, my links are set with `remote: true`

Now, I need to implement a similar feature, to update the custom `:approval` param of a post, but from the **calendar** `show.html.erb` view where all posts are displayed.

This is currently what I have in my **calendar** `show.html.erb` view:

```
<td class="cell_content_center post_approval_section">
  <% if post.approval == "ok" %>
    <span class="ok_green">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Approve Post"></span>
    <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "edit" %>
    <span class="edit_yellow">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Require Edits"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "remove" %>
    <span class="remove_red">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="To Be Deleted"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span>
</td>
```

This code allows me to actually update the post custom `:approval` param from the **calendar** `show.html.erb`.

But I can't figure out how to reload the page, or even better, just reload the `post_approval_section` `td` where the links are located.

I cannot re-use the exact same approach I used on the **post** `show.html.erb` since I already have a JS response for the `Posts#Update` action setup.

How can I make this work?

—————

**UPDATE**: based on Long Nguyen answer, here is where I am now.

```
#calendars/show.html.erb and calendars/_post_approval.html.erb

<td class="cell_content_center post_approval_section">
  <% if post.approval == "ok" %>
    <span class="ok_green">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), remote: true, approval_update: true, :method => :patch do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Approve Post"></span>
    <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "edit" %>
    <span class="edit_yellow">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), remote: true, approval_update: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Require Edits"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "remove" %>
    <span class="remove_red">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), remote: true, approval_update: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="To Be Deleted"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span>
</td>

#posts_controller.rb

def update
    if params["approval_update"]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :action => "update_post_approval" }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.update(post_params)
          format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
          format.js
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def update_post_approval
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

#update_post_approval.js.erb

$('td.post_approval_section').html('<%= j render(partial: "calendars/post_approval") %>');
```

When I click on one of the links to update a post approval, nothing happens in the browser.

But, in `log/development.log`, I have:

```
Started PATCH "/posts/42?post%5Bapproval%5D=edit" for ::1 at 2015-11-19 19:59:51 -0800
Processing by PostsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"approval"=>"edit"}, "id"=>"42"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35mPost Load (2.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 42]]
  [1m[36m (1.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.1ms)[0m  UPDATE "posts" SET "approval" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "posts"."id" = $3  [["approval", "edit"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-20 03:59:51.203371"], ["id", 42]]
  [1m[36mSQL (3.6ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "versions" ("event", "object", "whodunnit", "created_at", "object_changes", "item_id", "item_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["event", "update"], ["object", "---\nid: 42\ncalendar_id: 8\ndate: 2015-11-19 20:19:00.000000000 Z\nsubject: Armistice 2\nformat: Image\ncopy: Joyeux 11 novembre tout le monde. ++\ncreated_at: 2015-11-19 20:19:58.244685000 Z\nupdated_at: 2015-11-20 03:59:44.073894000 Z\nimage_file_name: armistice.jpg\nimage_content_type: image/jpeg\nimage_file_size: 35967\nimage_updated_at: 2015-11-19 20:19:57.792047000 Z\nshort_copy: etg'tg' <<\nscore: \nfacebook: true\ntwitter: true\ninstagram: false\npinterest: false\ngoogle: false\nlinkedin: false\ntumblr: \nsnapchat: \napproval: ok\n"], ["whodunnit", "1"], ["created_at", "2015-11-20 03:59:51.203371"], ["object_changes", "---\napproval:\n- ok\n- edit\nupdated_at:\n- 2015-11-20 03:59:44.073894000 Z\n- 2015-11-20 03:59:51.203371000 Z\n"], ["item_id", 42], ["item_type", "Post"]]
  [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered posts/_approval.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered posts/update.js.erb (2.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 10.9ms | ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

—————

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with 2 ideas to handle this situation:

**First way:** Pass another param in when you update the post from **calendar** `show.html.erb`, so the `link_to` will be:

```
<%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
```

Then in you Post controller on `update` action, you can filter this request by `approval_update` param:

```
if params["approval_update"]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :action => "update_post_approval" }
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
  ...
  end
end
```

Now when you update Post from **Calendar** show.html.erb, Post controller will load `RAILS_ROOT/app/views/posts/update_post_approval.js.erb` instead of `update.js.erb`

**Second way**: create another route for update the approval attribute of Post, which mean you will also create another action in Post controller to handle the case of AJAX update in **Calendar** page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying the **First way**. Is there a way to choose which .js.erb file is called in the `Posts#Update controller`?

Comment: Thanks for this addition. And then, I guess, in `update_post_approval.js.erb` I reload the partial that correspond to the div with the class `post_approval_section`, rigth? Also, do I need to create a new route for the new `update_post_approval`?

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my question to illustrate where I am now. Any chance you could take a look and let me know what is still wrong with this code?

Comment: Hey @ThibaudClement, you forgot to pass `approval_update` to `post_path` in `link_to`. It should be `<%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95641/discussion-between-thibaud-clement-and-long-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with a condition in the js.erb:

```
<% if @post.approval === 'ok' %>
    $('td.post_approval_section').replaceWith("<%= j render(:partial => 'calendar/approval') %>");
<% else %>
// you current update post code 
<% end %>
```

along with moving the code to ***_approval.html.erb***

```
  <% if post.approval == "ok" %>
    <span class="ok_green">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Approve Post"></span>
    <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "edit" %>
    <span class="edit_yellow">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Require Edits"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "remove" %>
    <span class="remove_red">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="To Be Deleted"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which must make sense to an experienced eye. Since I am a newbie, I have to say I am confused. I already have an '_approval.html.erb' file in `app/views/posts`. Also, what code should go where you say `// you current update post code`?