# Rails 4: update model attribute with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

***This is a follow-up question on [Rails 4: custom action to update only one param with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818197/rails-4-custom-action-to-update-only-one-param-with-ajax/33818296#33818296) and [Rails 4: select DOM element with dynamically generated id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820080/rails-4-select-dom-element-with-dynamically-generated-id/33821370#33821370).***

***I can't figure out how to make things work from the good answers I got, so I would like to start again from a blank slate.***

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `Calendar` and a `Post` models, set up with shallow routes:

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :posts, shallow: true
end
```

A calendar `has_many` post and a post `belong_to` a calendar.

In the calendar `show.html.erb` view, I display all the posts that belong to a calendar.

From this calendar `show.html.erb` view, I need to update the :approval param of a post, with an AJAX call, so that only the DOM element related to the :approval of this particular post is refreshed, not the entire page.

This is the part of the code in calendar `show.html.erb` that allows me to update the `:approval` of a post:

```
<tr id="post_row_<%= post.id%>"> 
  [...]  # Truncated for brivety 
  <td class="cell_content_center post_approval_section">
    <% if post.approval == "ok" %>
      <span class="ok_green">
    <% else %>
      <span class="approval_blue" %>
    <% end %>
      <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Approve Post"></span>
      <% end %>
    </span><br/>
    <% if post.approval == "edit" %>
      <span class="edit_yellow">
    <% else %>
      <span class="approval_blue" %>
    <% end %>
      <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Require Edits"></span>
    <% end %>
    </span><br/>
    <% if post.approval == "remove" %>
      <span class="remove_red">
    <% else %>
      <span class="approval_blue" %>
    <% end %>
      <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="To Be Deleted"></span>
    <% end %>
    </span>
  </td>
  [...]  # Truncated for brivety
</tr>
```

Then, in `posts_controller.rb`:

```
def update
    if params["approval_update"]
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.update(post_params)
          format.js { render :action => "update_post_approval" }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
        end
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.update(post_params)
          format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
          format.js
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def update_post_approval
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

***Note:*** here, I cannot use the default `Posts#Update` action, since it is already used by another AJAX call to update the `:approval` param from the post `show.html.erb` view, which the reason why we render the `update_post_approval` custom action.

Then, I have the following `app/views/posts/update_post_approval.js.erb` file:

```
$("tr#post_row_#{post.id} > td.post_approval_section").html('<%= j render(partial: "calendars/post_approval") %>');
```

Finally, I have the following `calendars/_post_approval.html.erb` partial:

```
<td class="cell_content_center post_approval_section">
  <% if post.approval == "ok" %>
    <span class="ok_green">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Approve Post"></span>
    <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "edit" %>
    <span class="edit_yellow">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Require Edits"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span><br/>
  <% if post.approval == "remove" %>
    <span class="remove_red">
  <% else %>
    <span class="approval_blue" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove", approval_update: true), remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="To Be Deleted"></span>
  <% end %>
  </span>
</td>
```

When I click one of the three links in the `<td class="cell_content_center post_approval_section">` section to update a post `:approval` param, the param is actually updated, as we can see in the server logs:

```
Started PATCH "/posts/38?approval_update=true&post%5Bapproval%5D=ok" for ::1 at 2015-11-20 08:03:50 -0800
Processing by PostsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"approval_update"=>"true", "post"=>{"approval"=>"ok"}, "id"=>"38"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 38]]
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "approval" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "posts"."id" = $3  [["approval", "ok"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-20 16:03:50.888587"], ["id", 38]]
  SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("event", "object", "whodunnit", "created_at", "object_changes", "item_id", "item_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["event", "update"], ["object", "---\nid: 38\ncalendar_id: 6\ndate: 2015-11-17 22:09:00.000000000 Z\nsubject: Subject\nformat: Link\ncopy: https://www.wid.la/\ncreated_at: 2015-11-17 22:09:28.713416000 Z\nupdated_at: 2015-11-20 16:03:20.613597000 Z\nimage_file_name: \nimage_content_type: \nimage_file_size: \nimage_updated_at: \nshort_copy: ''\nscore: \nfacebook: true\ntwitter: false\ninstagram: false\npinterest: false\ngoogle: false\nlinkedin: false\ntumblr: \nsnapchat: \napproval: remove\n"], ["whodunnit", "1"], ["created_at", "2015-11-20 16:03:50.888587"], ["object_changes", "---\napproval:\n- remove\n- ok\nupdated_at:\n- 2015-11-20 16:03:20.613597000 Z\n- 2015-11-20 16:03:50.888587000 Z\n"], ["item_id", 38], ["item_type", "Post"]]
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered calendars/_post_approval.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered posts/update_post_approval.js.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 9.9ms | ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)
```

However, unless I manually refresh the page, nothing changes on the view.

I have now spent hours on this issue and can't figure out whether the issue is caused by the Ruby or the JS code.

If necessary, I am happy to share more code.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try giving a print statement to print the post id in **app/views/posts/update_post_approval.js.erb** file, If it's getting updated according to logs, that means the issue is with js file. For very minute errors in js file, the functions written in the JS file will not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here:

*$("tr#post_row_**#{post.id}** > td.post_approval_section").html('<%= j render(partial: "calendars/post_approval") %>');*

**Updated**
It should be:

```
$("tr#post_row_<%= @post.id %> > td.post_approval_section").html('<%= j render(partial: "calendars/post_approval", locals: {post: @post}) %>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not seem to solve the problem. It causes an issue in the server logs: `NameError - undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007fab654e5990>:0x007fab69e1f160>:
  app/views/posts/update_post_approval.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts_update_post_approval_js_erb__1803217690360989333_70187072192720'`

Comment: Yes, I had that doubt, please change post to **@post**, and pass a local parameter in the partial: ```$("tr#post_row_<%= post.id %> > td.post_approval_section").html('<%= j render(partial: "calendars/post_approval", locals: {post: @post}) %>');```

Comment: Sir, you are a rock star. It is working perfectly, thank you so much.

Comment: Happy that it solved your problem, have faced this myself many times.